# Django render template within a template

Tags: python, django

I want to create a template for a component that is used many times on a single page, with very few changes (simply 2 or 3 variables).  How can I create this template and render it within another template?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

How about [include](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#include)?

Like so:

```
{% include "name_snippet.html" with person="Jane" greeting="Hello" %}
```

Answer (score 4):

We usually [create a custom inclusion tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#inclusion-tags) for this.

Comment: that looks good, but where do I put the python file that defines the tag method?

Comment: In one of your apps. See the top of the page.

Comment: i'm not finding what file i'm supposed to register it in though

Comment: Did you see the top of the page?

Comment: yeah, i can't find in that entire page what file i'm supposed to add the register calls to

Comment: ... What are you talking about? You use `{% load ... %}` to load it, you use a decorator or function call to register it, it just works!